# Best way to version AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have just released some AWS Lambda's, only stage I can see is test.  Now, should we create a prod stage and publish them to that?  Would this then mean I can work on the test/dev ones if changes need changing and this won't affect the prod stage ones?

Thanks

Comment: There are no "stages" in Lambda

Comment: Maybe I meant API Gateway then?  Just want to know way to version them so can release to test, production and qa.

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a new [version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html) each time a lambda is published. Assign different [aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html) like dev, test and prod as pointer to certain version. Always refer to a Lambda by Alias along with name from different applications(never with just version)

Or Simply create three different lambdas with names, simply suffixing -dev, -qa, etc and not worry about versions or aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Aliases now, seems to work well and is built-in.

Using event bridge rules to trigger lambda's either via S3 and API Gateway.